# "Coverings" and "covers" in Grothendieck topologies

Tags: general-topology, category-theory, grothendieck-topologies

Consider a topological space $X$, and an open cover of $X$. Now when choosing a Grothendieck topology we select "coverings", which in the case of $\mathcal O(X)$ should be open covers. But not every "cover" is a "covering", i.e. the disjoint union if the covering open sets need not form an unramified covering.

So why use the word "covering" and not just "cover" for Grothendieck topologies? Are there historical reasons? Or is there something wrong in my argument above?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The historical reason is that these terms were translated from French: a cover is *un recouvrement* and a covering is *un revêtement*.
This is one of the rare cases where French is less ambiguous than English.
For example the map  $ \:\mathbb S^1\to \mathbb S^1:(\cos t,\sin t)\mapsto  (\cos 2t,\sin 2t)$ is *un revêtement de* $\mathbb S^1$ and definitely not *un recouvrement* de $\mathbb S^1$.
Conversely the set of all open intervals $(n,n+2)\subset \mathbb R \;(n\in \mathbb Z)$ is *un recouvrement* de $\mathbb R$ and definitely not *un revêtement de* $\mathbb R$

Also note that the map $\mathbb C^*\to \mathbb C^*:z\mapsto z^2$ is both *un revêtement étale de* $\mathbb C^*$ and *un recouvrement pour la  la topologie étale de* $\mathbb C^*$ : one has to keep a clear mind here!

Comment: It is the other way around: a covering is _un revêtement_ while a cover is _un recouvrement_.

Comment: @Pece: I have browsed some topology books in English and you seem to be right. I have modified my text accordingly. Thanks for your comment.

Comment: " rare cases" : it's a bit surprising, I'm French and I have to admit I'm used to seeing ambiguities in English that aren't there in French; so I'd like to see where French is more ambiguous, to know where my language fucks up ( admittedly, it's not surprising that it does, given its overwhelming weirdness)

Comment: @Max: Say aloud "l'amoralité/la moralité  de ce politicien me surprend" Is the politician moral or amoral?  What does the written announcement  "plus de bus 17 à partir de demain"  mean? More or no more buses?

Comment: Oh alright, I thought you meant in mathematics !